# Choosing tool to add field based on nearest neighbor using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join, proximity, append

Using ArcMap, I have two feature classes. The first is my polygon parcel layer with crop type, irrigation type, owner, etc. The second is my line canal layer, which has a field for our water schedule (how many days until a farmer can take water again).

I need to determine if our water schedule has an impact on what methods farmers use to irrigate their fields.

Using the ESRI basic license, what tool would I use to add the water schedule field from the canal layer to my parcel layer, based on the closest canal? The canals do not intersect the parcel boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the Spatial Join (Analysis) tool and set it to Match Option - Closest.

[image]

Comment: This answered my question. Thank you.